# How to have default values for an attribute in Code First?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

Basically I'm trying to expand on the already created SimpleMembership of ASP.NET MVC 4.
I wanna add a balance field that has the initial value of 0.

I've tried with the following code and inserting nothing in the Balance field:

```
    [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string RealName { get; set; }
    public int Balance { get; set; }
}
```

But unfortunately I get an exception when I try to create a new user (without a balance) that I cannot insert null in balance since it doesn't allow nulls.
How can I get balance to be 0 as a default value in Code First.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
  int Balance
```

does not allow nulls but

```
  int? Balance
```

does.

If you want to controll the structure at the database level, use explicit migrations and manually tweak the generated migration code so that you set up a default value at the database level. If you want a default value at the code level, just set the value in the default constructor of the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot - but say I want the value to be 0 and not null.
I've tried the following which doesn't work:
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            Balance = 0;
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string RealName { get; set; }
        public int? Balance { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Set the default value in a constructor.

Comment: Well I did: 
public UserProfile() { Balance = 0; } 
But it doesn't set it to 0

Comment: Maybe this is not what you want, but you could always set the value in your controller before returning it to the view. 
var userProfile = new UserProfile{};
userProfile.Balance = 0;
...

Comment: Did you call the constructor or did you use an initialiser?

Answer (score 0):

First: You can use a constructor like this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string RealName { get; set; }
  public int Balance { get; set; }

  public UserProfile()
  {
     this.Balance = 0;
  }
}
```

Second, clean and rebuild solution, then use the migration command

```
Update-database -verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Integers have a default value of 0 by default. When you instantiate a new UserProfile, Balance should already be set to 0.

See: [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)